# Probability problem (with model)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across an interesting task in probability theory that I don't know how to solve. The task says the following: "Consider a person with $n \in \mathbb{N} $ boy/girlfriends. He/she wants to write a love letter to everyone with the lowest amount of work possible, which is why he/she uses the following method: Writes one letter and copies it $n$ times and writes the name of the boy/girlfriends on one of every letter (so that every name appears only once). He/she then adds addresses (only once) on $n$ envelopes and puts a letter in every envelope without looking at the names. What is the probability that he/she will have at least one boy/girlfriend left the next day? What happens as n gets larger? Also give the model you were using." I actually have no idea on how to solve this, but thought it sounds interesting, so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "left"? Maybe letter- envelope combination is correct?

Comment: What you are looking for is information about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa Yes, exactly. As one can probably tell I had to translate the task myself and the idea behind that is that every wrong combination will lead to splitting up. Therefore at least one is left, if at least one combination is correct. Sorry if my translation was confusing.

Comment: $P(\mathrm{At\, least\, 1\, letter\, in\, correct\, envelope}) = 1 - P(\mathrm{No\, letters\, in\, correct\, envelope}) = 1 - (\mathrm{Number\, of\, derangements\, of\, n\, items}) / (\mathrm{Number\, of\, permutations\, of\, n\, items}) = 1 - d_n / n!$